# Protobuf-net deserializes empty collection to null when the collection is a property of another type

Tags: protobuf-net

I've run in to a problem with protobuf-net and I hope it is user error and not a bug with protobuf-net.

I can serialize an empty collection (for example, `IDictionary<string, string>()`) and then deserialize the collection. The deserialization results in a non-null object (exactly as I serialized).

However, things get wonky if the collection belongs to another type. Serializing the custom type with a non-null empty collection results in a deserialization where the collection is null.

Below is an example of what I am working on and unit tests that illustrate the problem.

The test `Test_Protobuf_EmptyDictionary_SerializeDeserialize` passes.
The test `Test_Protobuf_EmptyCollectionAndPopulatedCollection_SerializeDeserialize` fails.

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(ConcreteA))]
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> FieldsA { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> FieldsB { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public ICollection<string> FieldsC { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public ICollection<string> FieldsD { get; set; } 
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(110, typeof(ConcreteB))]
public class ConcreteA : AbstractClass
{
    public ConcreteA() {}
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(120, typeof(ConcreteC))]
public class ConcreteB : ConcreteA
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ConcreteB() {}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ConcreteC : ConcreteB
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string HairColor { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ProtobufTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_Protobuf_EmptyDictionary_SerializeDeserialize()
    {
        IDictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ICollection<string> collection = new List<string>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(dictionary);
        Assert.IsNotNull(collection);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, dictionary.Keys.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, collection.Count);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, dictionary);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, string>>(ms);

            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, deserialized.Keys.Count);
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, collection);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<ICollection<string>>(ms);

            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, deserialized.Count);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_Protobuf_EmptyCollectionAndPopulatedCollection_SerializeDeserialize()
    {
        ConcreteC c = new ConcreteC {
                                        FieldsA = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
                                        FieldsB = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"john", "elway"}},
                                        FieldsC = new List<string>(),
                                        FieldsD = new List<string>{"james", "jones"}
                                    };
        Assert.IsNotNull(c);
        Assert.IsNotNull(c.FieldsA);
        Assert.IsNotNull(c.FieldsB);
        Assert.IsNotNull(c.FieldsC);
        Assert.IsNotNull(c.FieldsD);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, c.FieldsA.Keys.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, c.FieldsB.Keys.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, c.FieldsC.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, c.FieldsD.Count);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, c);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<ConcreteC>(ms);

            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized.FieldsA); // first failing test
            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized.FieldsB);
            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized.FieldsC);
            Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized.FieldsD);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, deserialized.FieldsA.Keys.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, deserialized.FieldsB.Keys.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, deserialized.FieldsC.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, deserialized.FieldsD.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ultimately, this comes down to the fact that the protobuf specification has no concept of `null`, and no way of expressing `null`. A collection is really just a `repeated` block (from the .proto specification); and a `repeated` block of 0 items is *nothing whatsoever*; no bytes; nothing. Since the collection member itself **does not appear** in protobuf, there is nowhere to say whether that thing is null vs not-null.

In xml terms, if is like using `[XmlElement]` to embed child items inside a parent (rather than `[XmlArray]` / `[XmlArrayItem]` - i.e.

```
<Foo>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Item>x</Item>
    <Item>y</Item>
    <Item>z</Item>
</Foo>
```

Here, a `Foo` with 0 `Item`s would be:

```
<Foo>
    <Name>abc</Name>
</Foo>
```

from which, it is impossible to say whether the collection itself was `null` vs *empty*. Obviously protobuf isn't actually xml, but the above is meant purely as an illustrative example.

So: protobuf has no way to express this scenario, and therefore neither does protobuf-net.

In the other scenario you represent: the serialized representation of an empty list (as the root element) is: zero bytes. When you deserialize, if it finds the stream is empty, it always returns a non-null value as the root object, that being the most *likely* version of what you wanted.

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior? Types that go over-the-wire which is a big use case of Protobuf tend to be immutable and usually refrain fron using Null. I would argue null should never be used and having an empty list instead should be the default value; at the very least for collection IEnumerable based fields on a type an empty list for collections would be the more common case for users. Is there an attribute or something that we could apply to the field to distinguish this case on a field-by-field basis?

Comment: @akara not currently; however, you can just initialize the property in the constructor - or in C# "current": `List<Foo> Foos {get;} = new List<Foo>();`

Comment: @MarcGravell Nice explanation with XmlArrayAttribute. Only difference I can think of in terms of behavior; XML Deserialize will initialize all the collection to empty collection instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have a public default constructor so protobuf-net can give you an empty object.